# Order Deny, Allow, Deny from IP isn't blocking IP address, Not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, ip, blocking, httpforbiddenhandler

```
order allow,deny
deny from 1.0.1.0/24
deny from 1.0.2.0/23
deny from 1.0.32.0/19
deny from 1.0.8.0/21
deny from 1.1.0.0/24
allow from all
```

I am using the above code to block the IP in `.htaccess`. **But it's not working**. If I remove `"allow from all"`, then the website gives `forbidden for all IP address`. 
What is the problem with this ?

The httpd configuration is as follow:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/foldername/>
      Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      </Directory>
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: just put `abcd` in your `.htaccess` file and see if the site broke or not. if it doesn't break, it means it's not respecting `.htaccess`. you need to enable `sudo a2enmod rewrite` in case of failure.

Comment: @jagad89 I have several redirection set in htaccess which are working fine. Thus htaccess is working. However, the deny Ip isn't working.

Comment: @jagad89 - Since they say that the behavior changes if they remove a line from their htaccess, I would say that's evidence for it being used. Also, as far as I know, the rewrite module doesn't have anything to do with any of the above rules.